# Thought Experiment Spaceship Accelerating from Earth

Tags: general-relativity

From Earth, a spaceship is observed accelerating away at a constant acceleration of $g=9.81 m/s^2$.

As the spaceship continues to accelerate, how would people on Earth see the spaceship's acceleration? Would we still see it accelerate at $g$ or will it change?

Comment: We would see a hyperbolic trajectory with an asymptotic velocity $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would change as seen by the observer, which it starts to decelerate. This is caused by the limit of causality speed $c$, and therefore you need to take the effect of time dilation and length contraction into account. You can calculate the acceleration of spaceship as seen by observers on Earth by the equation: $$A=a\gamma^{-3}$$ where $A$ is the acceleration as seen by observer, $a$ is the acceleration of the spaceship and $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.

If you plot a v-t graph of function $V=at/\gamma$, you would see that the velocity asymptotically approaches c as seen in the picture that I attached. [look at the sky blue line in the graph]

*(Simply differentiate the function to obtain the acceleration.)

[image]